# Why are my Angular.js expressions not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

im very new to Angular.js and i cant seem to get my expression to display the values from my controller, it just sees it as a string when i view it. i have no idea why. Am i missing something super obvious?, any help would be appreciated.

Im also using node.js just to set up my local server, but i dont believe this is the problem.

```js
var appdemo = angular.module('appdemo', []);

appdemo.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value1 = 1;
  $scope.value2 = 2;

  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    $scope.x = $scope.value1 + ' x ' + $scope.value2 +
      " = " (+$scope.value1 + +$scope.value2)
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appdemo">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>appdemo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span>times</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value1" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="value2" />

    <button ng-click="updateValue()">total</button> {{x}} {{ value1 }}
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is my local server not entirely convinced if done it correctly.

```
 const express = require('express')

 const app = express()

 app.use(express.static("public"))

 app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile)
 app.set("view engine", "html")
 app.set("views", "./views")

 app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
 res.render("index")

 })

 app.listen(3000, ()=>{
 console.log("Running on port 3000...")
})
```

file structure:

```
 node_mdodules
 public
    css
 views
    index.html
    main.js 
 app.js
 package-lock.json
 package.json
```

Comment: I ran this code and the `value1` and `value2` were interpolated correctly

Comment: ok well then im not sure why it wont work for me possible how i set up my local server

Comment: yea i think your right messed up the file structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume you have the next folder structure:

```
-App name
    -public
       -html
          -index.html
       -js
          -main.js
       -style.css
    -server.js //Or any other name for your node js server
```

In your server js you should use the `__dirname` property:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then in your html replace your import script for this:

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: yea problem was the file structure thanks a bunch, pretty stupid on my part